# Каким образом подгружается Oracle Driver и почему в моем случае этого не происходит?

Tags: java, oracle, maven, веб-программирование

Настраиваю приложение разработанное в Anypoint Studio на работу с Oracle.
В проекте подключение настраивается следующим образом:

```
<spring:bean id="ESMpooledDatasource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <spring:property name="driverClass">
            <spring:value>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</spring:value>
        </spring:property>
        <spring:property name="jdbcUrl">
            <spring:value>${esm.db.connection_string}</spring:value>
        </spring:property>
        <spring:property name="user">
            <spring:value>${esm.db.username}</spring:value>
        </spring:property>
        <spring:property name="password">
            <spring:value>${esm.db.password}</spring:value>
        </spring:property>
        <spring:property name="minPoolSize">
            <spring:value>3</spring:value>
        </spring:property>
        <spring:property name="maxPoolSize">
            <spring:value>8</spring:value>
        </spring:property>
        <spring:property name="properties">
            <spring:ref bean="ESMpooledDatasourceProperty" />
        </spring:property>
    </spring:bean>
    <spring:bean id="ESMpooledDatasourceProperty" class="net.extracode.mule.jdbc.utils.SessionTraceDBProps">
        <spring:constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="${esm.db.username}" />
        <spring:constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="${esm.db.password}" />
    </spring:bean>
```

Сборка Maven-ом проходит гладко. В pom.xml ojdbc6 подключен:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Но при выполнении, ругается:

```
WARN  com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource - Could not load driverClass oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

Comment: Судя по ошибке - нет jar-ника с драйвером JDBC для Oracle. Проверьте что он есть и прописан в classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавление в classpath к сожалению не помогло.
Проблема решилась тем, что библиотека была добавлена в папку lib/user на локальном сервере AnypointStudio: AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.3.7.0_5.2.0.201508051354\mule\lib\user